# ios ionic app crash on simulator while running proper on real devices

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

iOS app is running properly on real devices but when trying to install and open on simulator then app crashes.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ran the command - ionic Cordova emulate ios
2. Then the app installed on simulator and simulator open the app but it shows blank screen around 3-5 seconds and then automatically gets closed.

Again when i tried to open through simulator then again app open and shows blank screen around 3-5 seconds and then automatically gets closed. Not able to see console. log through safari debugging since is not opening. Did a lot of research from last 3 days but still problem is not solved.

I use XCode 10. When I try to open it on real device its working fine.

Ionic information:

```
ionic 3.20.0
cordova 6.5.0
```

Comment: did you resolved this?